# Error on Event Registration Page

Tags: civievent

We created and event without problem however once someone clicks the Register Now buttom on the page the following message is seen. I am running version 5.9.0

Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to member your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred.
You do not have permission to access this page.

Return to home page.

The full error trace is below please help.

```
**BACKTRACE**
#0 /var/www/html/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/ca.bidon.reporterror/CRM/ReportError/Utils.php(31): reporterror_civicrm_generatereport("Jamaica Teachers Association", (Array:2), NULL, (Array:0))
#1 /var/www/html/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/ca.bidon.reporterror/CRM/ReportError/Handler/FormsNoReferer.php(54): CRM_ReportError_Utils::sendReport((Array:2), (Array:0))
#2 /var/www/html/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/ca.bidon.reporterror/reporterror.php(168): CRM_ReportError_Handler_FormsNoReferer::handler((Array:2), (Array:0))
#3 /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(368): reporterror_civicrm_handler((Array:2))
#4 /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Event/Form/Registration.php(265): CRM_Core_Error::fatal("You do not have permission to access this page.")
#5 /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Event/Form/Registration/Register.php(107): CRM_Event_Form_Registration->preProcess()
#6 /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(585): CRM_Event_Form_Registration_Register->preProcess()
#7 /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Display.php(92): CRM_Core_Form->buildForm()
#8 /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Display->perform(Object(CRM_Event_Form_Registration_Register), “display”)
#9 /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Event_Form_Registration_Register), “display”)
#10 /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(351): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("display")
#11 /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(309): CRM_Core_Controller->run((Array:3), NULL)
#12 /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(84): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:15))
#13 /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))
#14 /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(445): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
#15 /var/www/html/includes/menu.inc(527): civicrm_invoke("event", “register”)
#16 /var/www/html/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
#17 {main}
```

Answer (score 4):

From the error it looks like the user doesn't have necessary permission to access the page. You will need to give permission to user to register online.

Thanks

Pradeep

Comment: As in there are Permissions in your CMS that relate to accessing features in civicrm and it seems like you are missing some.

Comment: I had already checked the permissions and all of those were set as needed so there is clearly something else happening here.

Answer (score 2):

I eventually figured out the issue. First the problem was with fees and a setting in the contribution component namley "Automatically update related contributions when Membership Type is changed". Once this was selected the issue resolved. This seemed to have been added with later versions of civicrm